# socket.io on('connection') triggers without actual connections

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.set('log level', 1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

after running

```
node server.js
```

sometimes 'connected' is logged to console without actual connection where does it come from?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a page opened in some browser?

Comment: @Krasimir can the browser connect even if I close the tab which started that connection?

Comment: Nope. It should. But sometimes you may forgot a tab or another window. It happened with me.

Comment: @Krasimir I can't reproduce this with my browser closed, but if I connect using some local page and then close it and then restart server the connection triggers again

Comment: Looks like browser is reconnecting the lost connection.

Comment: @user568109 with tab closed?

Comment: If with tab closed then it is likely a bug, like [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765738). Browser should not reconnect then.